# partial derivatives and integrals

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

suppose I have a function $$v(x,t):=\int_0^t u(x,t;s) ds.$$

Why $$v_t(x,t)=u(x,t;t)+\int_0^t u(x,t;s) ds.$$

I do not know where does the $u(x,t;t)$ term come from ?

Comment: Your final term, the integral, is missing a derivative, ought to have $u_t$. See Leibniz’s rule.

Comment: I replaced $u(x,t)$ with $v(x,t)$. You were using the same symbol to denote two different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just had $ v ( t ) = \int _ { s = 0 } ^ t u ( s ) \, \mathrm d s $, then you'd say that $ \mathrm D _ t v ( t ) = u ( t ) $.  Bump $ u ( s ) $ up to $ u ( x ; s ) $, and now you get $ u ( x ; t ) $.  Bump it further to $ u ( x , t ; s ) $, and now you get $ u ( x , t ; t ) $.

Since $ u ( x , t ; s ) $ has an additional dependence on $ t $, you get another term, $ \int _ { s = 0 } ^ t \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ; s ) \, \mathrm d s $.  But you weren't confused about where that term came from.  (However, as @Aruralreader mentioned in a comment, this does need a derivative with respect to $ t $ in it.)

Comment: I do not follow very clearly why based on the fact that: Since $ u ( x , t ; s ) $ has an additional dependence on $ t $, you get another term, $ \int _ { s = 0 } ^ t \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ; s ) \, \mathrm d s $. Why have we chosen exactly this shape of that term based solely on the fact that it depends on $t$: $ \int _ { s = 0 } ^ t \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ; s ) \, \mathrm d s $ ??

Comment: Perhaps I should add this to the answer; I didn't address it since you already had that term (or a term like it).  But again, consider a simpler example; suppose that $ v ( x , t ) = \int _ { s = 0 } ^ a u ( x , t ) \, \mathrm d s $.  Of course, in this case, $ v ( x , t ) = a u ( x , t ) $, and so naturally $ \mathrm D _ t v ( x , t ) = a \, \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ) $, but we can also write this as $ \int _ { s = 0 } ^ a \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ) \, \mathrm d s $.  …

Comment: …  Now if it's more complicated, with $ v ( x , t ) = \int _ { s = 0 } ^ a u ( x , t ; s ) \, \mathrm d s $, we can't evaluate the integral, but we still have $ \mathrm D _ t v ( x , t ) = \int _ { s = 0 } ^ a \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ; s ) \, \mathrm d s $.  Finally, if $ v ( x , t ) = \int _ { s = 0 } ^ t \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ; s ) \, \mathrm d s $, then $ v ( x , t ) $ depends on $ t $ in two different ways, so $ \int _ { s = 0 } ^ t \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ; s ) \, \mathrm d s $ is only one of the terms of $ \mathrm D _ t v ( x , t ) $.

Comment: I've got stuck once again.Why is it $v(x,t)=au(x,t)$ ?

Comment: In the simplified case where $ v ( x , t ) = \int _ { s = 0 } ^ a u ( x , t ) \, \mathrm d s $, you can actually evaluate the integral (since you're just integrating a constant with respect to $ s $ and get $ u ( x , t ) s \rvert _ { s = 0 } ^ a = u ( x , t ) ( a ) - u ( x , t ) ( 0 ) = a u ( x , t ) $.  (And you can also evaluate the integral $ \int _ { s = 0 } ^ a \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ) \, \mathrm d s $ and get $ a \, \mathrm D _ t u ( x , t ) $ and verify that this is what $ \mathrm D _ t v ( x , t ) $ is in this simplified case.)

Answer (score 0):

Receipt: By linearity of multidimensional derivatives, supply an index to  the symbol t at all places where it appears, do the differential and discard the indices by restriction to the diagonal $t=t_1=t_2$.

$$d \ \int_0^{t_1} u(x,t_2,s) ds  = dt_1 \partial_{t_1}\int_0^{t_1} u(x,t_2,s) ds + dt_2 \partial_{t_2}\int_0^{t_1} u(x,t_2,s) ds$$ $$\to  dt \left( u(x,t,t) + \int_0^t \partial_t u(x,t,s) ds \right)  $$

This yields the same result as the conventional $1/h$-limits, again by linearity of linearizations. Even the high school analysis rules for $$(1*x)' =1'x + 1 x' , n x=x+x+\dots, x^n = x*x*\dots $$ are simple consequences of the basic rule: look for all linear occurences of the symbol, replace it by 1 and add.